# Fulling updating setState in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the `reactjs` docs for `setState`:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> The second (optional) parameter is a callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

What if I just wanted to update my state, do I create a callback that does nothing?

Answer (score 2):

As they write **setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition.** because it works in an asynchronous way. So if you want to perform an action immediately after setting state on a state variable then a callback will be useful.

For Example

```
setState(
  { name: "Hello World" },
  () => console.log(this.state)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback is optional so you can do `this.setState({ key: value });`.